# IIS 7 / Pure ASP Issue with file uploading

Tags: iis, iis-7, asp-classic, vb6, vbscript

```
I have the following assets-
1. IIS Server 7.0
2. VBScript 5.0
3. Windows Server 2008
4. ADO 6.0
```

Server's Limit of Upload is - 1037408412 bytes.
Server's Requests Timeout Duration is - 3600 seconds (~1 hour).

And I am unable to upload file from browser to server. I can use the filesystemobject to read and write file but I cannot get the uploaded file using any thing. I even cannot use the
Request.ReadBinary method. When I print Request.TotalBytes it says 0. Only error message the server shows is-

> An error occurred on the server when processing the URL. Please
>   contact the system administrator. If you are the system administrator
>   please click here to find out more about this error.

Can anyone explain me what is the problem?
AND
Can anyone show me any way to upload file through pure asp ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We're running classic ASP here and honestly I can tell you from experience that trying to do this in classic ASP is a huge pain. If possible, do yourself a favor and even if you don't want to migrate all your code to ASP.net, you should at least use ASP.net for pages that need uploading.

A huge portion of our website is written in classic ASP, so I was reluctant to have one odd page that uses ASP.net, but that's honestly the best solution from my personal experience.

If you're absolutely set on using classic ASP, there's basically 2 ways to do it. You can use a purpose-built COM object such as [AspUpload](http://www.aspupload.com/) or [SA-FileUp](http://fileup.softartisans.com/) (although I'm not sure if SA-FileUp works on ASP classic anymore). The other way is to use native ASP code, of which I could find a few examples; [FreeASPUpload](http://www.freeaspupload.net/), [ASP Uploader](http://aspuploader.com/) or [Pure ASP File Upload](http://www.codeguru.com/csharp/.net/net_asp/article.php/c19297/Pure-ASP-File-Upload.htm) (the latter being what I stumbled across when I looked at this problem a few years ago.

So in summary, it looks like there's a few options floating around but for whatever reason, I remember when we did this same thing a few years ago, I ended up being unhappy with the pure ASP solutions, biting the bullet and writing an ASP.net page to handle uploads.